# Any workarounds for the PHP fgetcsv bug where whitespace is trimmed?

Tags: php, csv

Given the following string of CSV data (I am unable to ensure the fields are quoted)

```
AB,CD,   EF,GH,   IJ
```

and PHP code of:

```
$arr = fgetcsv($f);
```

(assuming $f is a valid file-pointer reading a file containing the above text) - one would expect this result:

```
Array('AB', 'CD', '   EF', 'GH', '   IJ');
```

when in fact you get:

```
Array('AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH', 'IJ');
```

This is problematic if you need positional context within that field.

Any **workarounds** of still being able to take advantage of fgetcsv, but ensuring that whitespace is not lost?

The bug is reported here: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53848

Comment: That's news to me. The PHP behaviour is pretty much what I would expect. Anyway, you can just use `explode(",", $line)` since that is actually what you want.

Comment: @mario: But that doesn't work in every case.

Comment: @mario: I want to take advantage of fgetcsv when possible, especially with quoted fields if they are available.

Comment: You cannot take advantage of fgetcsv if it doesn't do what you want. I could write you a regex to quote unquoted fields. But it would be saner to just use said thing for extraction.

Comment: This guy published a workaround here: http://thuejk.blogspot.com/
I haven't tested yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oooops. S**t.
I accidently already wrote a function which doesn't strip the spaces:

```
function str_getcsv2($line, $del=",", $q='"', $esc="\\") {
    $line = rtrim($line, "\r\n");
    preg_match_all("/\G ([^$q$del]*) $del | $q(( [$esc$esc][$q]|[^$q]* )+)$q $del /xms", "$line,", $r);
    foreach ($r[1] as $i=>$v) {  // merge both captures
        if (empty($v) && strlen($r[2][$i])) {
            $r[1][$i] = str_replace("$esc$q", "$q", $r[2][$i]);  // remove escape character
        }
    }
    return($r[1]);
}
```

Use it like:

```
$arr = str_getcsv2(fgets($f));
```